Visual Studio Code no funciona con Git y GitHub en Ubuntu 24.04.01 LTS
Hace varios días que estoy intentando resolver un conflicto que tengo con Visual Studio Code, utilizando repositorios GIT para trabajar tanto local como remotamente en GitHub. Intentaré explicar y detallar este problema lo mejor posible.
Todo empieza iniciando un repositorio local desde la terminal integrada de Visual Studio Code. Normalmente uno utiliza el comando git init desde la terminal de Visual y no tendría ningún problema...
Imagen que muestra el uso del comando git init
Luego de inicializar el repositorio local, el siguiente paso es hacer git add <file> que en mi caso quiero subir todos los archivos existentes en mi carpeta de trabajo, por lo que utilizaría git add . y luego haría commit con git commit -m "<text>".
Imagen que muestra el uso del comando git add . y comandos git commit -m "..."
Hasta este punto pude trabajar con normalidad con mi repositorio local, el problema empezó cuando tuve que subir mi repositorio local a mi repositorio remoto en GitHub. Ya que al realizar el siguiente script ocurre lo siguiente:
Script de git y primer git push
Logro realizar el primer git push hasta aquí todo normal, pero al cerrar y volver a abrir Visual Studio Code desde la carpeta donde estaba trabajando empieza el problema. Y es que Visual Studio Code se congela por un momento y luego procede a indicar el mensaje de error para cerrar el programa.
Error que describo
Este mismo error también ocurre cuando clono un repositorio remoto con git clone <url> y dicho repositorio contiene un archivo .git.
He intentado eliminar la carpeta .git y rehacer el repositorio desde cero, pero cuando quiero rehacer el script y hacer un git push me aparece otro error, que es el siguiente:
Error redoing git commands
Trabajo con un Linux Ubuntu 24.04.01 LTS
En otra instancia, también he intentado usar la terminal Linux para hacer los comandos, pero el final es el mismo, siempre que hay una carpeta .git que enlaza a un repositorio remoto de GitHub, Visual Studio Code se congela y se cierra.

Agrega la solución como respuesta, no dentro de la pregunta.  Léete [ask] y [answer] y haz el [tour] para entender mejor el funcionamiento de este sitio, gracias.

Muchas gracias, soy nuevo en la plataforma; lo tendré en cuenta.

Solución:
El problema está en los controladores de la tarjeta
gráfica NVIDIA (o eso creo, ya que esta solución parece funcionar bien hasta ahora), para poder solucionar este problema tuve que descargar los controladores manualmente desde la terminal Linux usando estos comandos y luego reiniciar la computadora.
Comandos:
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-470
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-550


Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas en el centro de ayuda.
